# Make [watchos-*] tag synonyms of [watchos] to be consistent with [watchos-3]'s status

Tags: feature-request, tags

**[watchos-3](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/watchos-3) is currently a tag synonym of [watchos](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/watchos).** In less technical terms, this means any posts tagged with [watchos-3](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/watchos-3) are actually tagged with [watchos](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/watchos).

If you don't know what tag synonyms are, you can just think of it like a website redirecting you, but instead it's a tag. This [help page](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) on the privilege of suggesting tag synonyms describes what happens when you ask with a tag synonym as one of your tags:

> #### What happens when a question is asked using a synonym?
>
> Any tags that match active synonyms will be automatically and silently changed from their original as-entered form to the tag that the synonym points to.
>
> This also increments a synonym counter, which you can view at /tags/synonyms to evaluate the effectiveness (or ineffectiveness) of the synonyms that are in place.

Anyways, [watchos-2](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/watchos-2), [watchos-3](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/watchos-3), and [watchos-4](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/watchos-4), all existing versions of [watchos](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/watchos), are not tag synonyms for it. I think this should be updated to clear confusion and make everything more uniform.

Answer (score 2):

## Yes, let's do this and make [watchos-4](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/watchos-4) (and other version tags) synonyms of [watchos](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/watchos).

This, as shown in the feature request, would make the tagging consensus more uniform and would cause less confusion. There shouldn't only be one version-specific tag that is a synonym!

Answer (score 1):

I'm tempted to just merge all the watchOS versions down to watchOS and leave no synonyms.

1. There have been 47 questions ever with any flavor of watchOS tag, ever.
2. One time the watchOS-3 synonym was used, ever.

For such a low volume, adding a bunch of synonyms seems a low return for effort.